# On conflict replace in Postgresql - while loading a external file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-copy

I'm considering to use 'COPY' command to load the text file into table A.

```
COPY myTable FROM value.txt (DELIMITER('|'));
```

A table has already 10 rows and the value.txt file also has the same 10 rows but only 1 column value(CheckTime) is different from the previous table data.
With SQLite 'on conflict replace' feature, I could manage to keep the other column values the same and only CheckTime value is refreshed.

I need to the same thing in PostgreSQL.

How can I do this thing?
Can you share your idea?

Answer (score 1):

COPY cannot do this. You will have to COPY the file into a temporary table and then use UPDATE to update the table you want the data in.

Answer (score 0):

Load to a staging table and you can perform and insert with an on conflict do.

Performs the same as a merge. Documentation here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html